# what is the relation between Heat and Black ash?

Tags: thermodynamics

Why something when burns completely and the residue after burning left with black ash why don't they are red or green or any colour?

Comment: Is that even true?  Wood ash is usually closer to white if it's fully burnt.  From my experience blacker ash has more unburnt products.  This is also more a chemistry question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a chemistry question.

Comment: @JMac where you seen burnt wood white?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ash  "The darker the wood ashes, the higher the content of remaining charcoal will be due to incomplete combustion."

Answer (score 1):

Combustion is basically a fuel+oxygen exothermic reaction. In several cases, some form of carbon (wood, coal, paper, etc.) is used:

***C + O<sub>2</sub> = 2CO<sub>2</sub>***

Some of the carbon in the above equation doesn't burn due to insufficient oxygen. The unburnt carbon is the ash. The worse the combustion, the darker the ash. The darkness is owed to the amount of carbon present. Carbon is black, and so the ash is black.

Comment: Burnt carbon is black or just carbon?

Comment: +MentalShakya Carbon is black in general.

Comment: What you say about diamond?

Comment: +MentalShakya Most forms of carbon are black, not all forms. Diamond has a crystalline lattice, making it transparent.

Comment: is this possible that diamond is not burnt whereas coal is burnt?

Comment: Your English is quite hard to comprehend, and your grammar is very hard to correct. 

Ash is a form of carbon, like diamond or coal. In the 'ash' form, it is black. There are also many other forms of carbon that are black, but there are exceptions.

Coal is not ash, and diamonds aren't either. Coal isn't already 'burnt'.

Comment: can I use Hindi?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65048/discussion-between-mental-shakya-and-aditya-radhakrishnan).

Comment: I absolutely cannot speak hindi.

Answer (score 1):

The colour of the ash depends on what is being burned. Most organic materials produce white, grey or black ash due to the presence of carbon and a mix of inorganic oxides. However, burning ammonium dichromate produces green chromium oxide [1]. Iron can oxidize into reddish $\mathrm{Fe}_2\mathrm{O}_3$. Hydrogen can be burned into transparent water. So there is no general rule indicating how heating changes the colour.

Still, burning a mixture of things will produce an impure mix of oxides, unburned carbon, and other remnants. This is unlikely to have a pure colour, and will likely have a fairly even absorption spectrum in visible light - hence looking greyish. But the exact shade depends on what is being burned.

[1] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6kGJsErEDc0

Comment: cool. So it is not discovered yet how colour form.?

Comment: @Mental Shakya: Well, how substances acquire their colours is pretty well understood - it all depends on how their electrons can absorb photons, which depends on what energy levels they have in the molecules. But this has nothing to do with combustion.

Comment: Ooo... But why it has nothing to do with combustion as it form only during combustion?